# How are non-square matrices used in computer graphics?

Tags: 3d, glsl, matrix-multiplication

Normally, square matrices are used to transform various points.  You have a 4D vector which transforms into a 1x4 or 4x1 matrix, which is multiplied by a 4x4 matrix on whichever side works to create a 4x1 or 1x4 matrix.  This is your transformed point.

But what are non-square matrices used for?  If you multiply a 3x4 matrix by a 4x1 vector matrix, you end up with a 3x1 matrix; that's one less dimension than what you started with.  Not to mention that a 3x4 matrix doesn't have the nice properties of a 4x4 matrix such as the ability to multiply by other 4x4 matrices and still retain the same dimensions.

GLSL supports both square matrices and non-square matrices.  Why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use 4x3 matrices for, for example, skeleton bone transformations in skinning. These transformations are affine and don't include projection, so you don't need the last column.

The result of the multiplication of 1x4 vector and 4x3 matrix is a 1x3 vector, and in this particular case you don't need to multiply it with a matrix.

Passing 4x3 matrices to GPU instead of 4x4 will save you a quarter of bandwidth.